# c# mysql wait for previous query to finish

Tags: c#, mysql

This is part of my code in c#

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
connection.Open();
cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
...
int xxxx;
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE myTable SET ..... ";
xxxx = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Debug.WriteLine(xxxx + " rows updated");

cmd.CommandText = "select id,... from myTable";
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
...
```

The first query (the update) will take about 30 seconds to execute.
What i observe, is that maybe the second query is executed before query1 having updated the table.

- Is this what is supposed to happen according to this code?
- Is there a way to prevent this from happening (i.e. complete 1st query and then execute 2nd one)

Comment: No, that is not supposed to happen. Are you absolutely sure that it **is** happening?

Comment: well, not 100% sure. that's why i said maybe. I've just added some code in the beginning about cmd. So, what is supposed to happen is that cmd can only have one "instance" and every query has to finish before starting next one, right?

Comment: @Thanos Darkadakis: the queries are executed one after another

Answer (score 1):

`ExecuteNonQuery()` method is synchronous and the next statement won't be executed until it is completed. The same applies to `ExecuteReader()`.

Those 2 queries cannot be run in parallel in the code above (at least from one thread. If the code above is running on multiple threads, it can happen).

There are also corresponsing asynchronous methods `ExecuteNonQueryAsync()` and `ExecuteReaderAsync()` but they are not use in the code above.